# How to position subtitle above title in Android Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am using

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp" />
```

with

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(myTitle);
toolbar.setSubtitle(mySubtitle);
```

to set the title and subtitle in my Toolbar. They are displayed with the subtitle beneath the title.

However, how can I make the subtitle appear ***above*** the title?

To get the desired effect, I could make the title look like a subtitle (and vice versa), but is there a better, non-hacky solution?

Comment: It's not possible to position a subtitle over title in default toolbar for that you'll need to create a custom toolbar and use a relative layout to achieve what you want

Comment: Can you post a snippet that shows how to do this? (I've tried adding a new subtitle **TextView** with `android:layout_gravity="top|start"` within the **Toolbar** xml, but it's being displayed the right of the title.)

Comment: Yes sure please wait

Comment: Please consider marking my answer as correct if it helped i'll appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want subtitle textview above title then use linear layout with vertical orientation or if you want it on top of the title use a relative layout and remove orientation:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <Textview
          android:id="@+id/Subtitle"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Subtitle"
          />
    <Textview
          android:id="@+id/Title"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Title"
          />


          </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is pretty much what I already did - except your Toolbar now has an additional title TextView. Can this be modified so that calling `toolbar.setTitle(myTitle)` and `toolbar.setSubtitle(mySubtitle)` yield the required result?